# If $X$ is an elliptic curve, what is the image of $P$ under the map determined by $|3P|$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

This is a step in a proof of a longer theorem (Hartshorne IV.4.6). In this situation we have an elliptic curve $X$ and a fixed point $P \in X$ so that the linear system $|3P|$ is very ample and of dimension $2$, embedding $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^2$.

In the proof, we take a basis $1, x, y \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(3P))$ which satisfy $$y^2 = x(x - 1)(x - \lambda)$$ in the homogeneous coordinate ring of the embedding $\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(3nP))$, which expresses the image of $X$ as the zero locus of $zy^2 = x(x - z)(x - \lambda z)$.

It is then claimed that $P \mapsto [0 : 1 : 0]$ under this embedding, since $1, x, y$ are chosen so that they have poles at $P$, which I don't understand. How can we calculate the image of $P$ and verify this?

Thanks!

I summarize how I tried to understand it below.

Explicitly, this map will be $Q \mapsto [1(Q): x(Q): y(Q)]$ so we just need to show $1(P) = y(P) = 0$. On the other hand, in the proof we chose $1, x$ to be so that they form a basis of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(2P)) \subset \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(3P))$. Moreover $Q \mapsto [1(Q) :x(Q)]$ is a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$. This is also the linear projection of $X$ onto the $x$-axis.

I'm also not sure why under this projection, $P \mapsto [0: 1]$ either since we could apply an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ to use the same linear system $|2P|$, to send $P$ to anything, right? I assume the conditions (the equation in particular) on the sections we chose would impose some kind of obstruction to this, but I don't see it. Perhaps one could argue that the the morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ is induced by the field extension $$k(x) \subset k(x)[y]/(y^2 - x(x - 1)(x - \lambda))$$ for example, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $X\to\Bbb P^2$ sends $P_0\mapsto [x(P_0):y(P_0):1]$. $x$ is chosen to have a pole of order 2 at $P$, and $y$ is chosen to have a pole of order $3$ at $P$. In order to make $[x(P):y(P):1]$ be represented by regular functions near $P$ which aren't all zero at $P$, we should multiply by a function $f$ that has a zero of order 3 at $P$. This gives that $P$ is mapped to $[f\cdot x(P):f\cdot y(P): f]$, and since $f\cdot x$ and $f$ have a zero of positive order at $P$ while $f\cdot y$ has neither a zero nor a pole, we have that $P\mapsto [0:1:0]$.

The reason this works is that the local ring at $P$ is a discrete valuation ring, so we can find a function $f$ of the specified valuation, lift it to an open neighborhood of $P$, and then use this to extend our map over $P$ by noting that on the intersection of $D(f)$ and our original domain of definition, $[x:y:1]=[fx:fy:f]$. This is a (very computational!) instance of the curve-to-projective extension theorem, which you can find a fair amoutn of material about both here on MSE and in Vakil's notes (or by googling).

Comment: +1, of course. But fwiw I would like to add the explicit remark: if $D$ is a divisor (on a smooth variety $X$, say) then one has that $\mathop{\rm div} (1_D) = D$, if "one views $1=1_D$ as a rational section of the sheaf ${\cal L} = {\cal O} (D)$". So, in the OP's case, "$1_D(P)=0$." It 'might' be better to write  $\mathop{\rm div}_{\cal L} 1 = D$ - for notational attribution, you might like to see my old answer and embarrassing comments to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994463/what-is-the-canonical-meromorphic-section-1-d-of-mathcal-o-xd

Comment: Are we also using the fact that $1$ is chosen to have a pole of order 2 at $P$ as well?

Comment: In the same vein can we assume $1$ has a pole of order 1 at $P$? Sorry - using $1$ to represent a rational function with nontrivial poles is very confusing.

Comment: Thankfully to me $1$ is just $1$ here. There's this sort of nasty subtlety here where the divisor of a rational function $f$ as a global section of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ (what peter writes above as $div_\mathcal{L}f$) is $D$ plus the divisor of $f$ as a rational function - what I'm thinking of here is really these sections as rational functions on our elliptic curve. This means that *as rational functions* 1 has no poles nor zeroes, $x$ has a pole of order 2 at $P$, and $y$ has a pole of order 3 at $P$.

Comment: @Daniel, do look at my link for an explanation of how one can view $1$ as having non-trivial poles/zeros.

Comment: +1. It might be worth noting for concreteness that one can simply take $f = 1/y$ as a function with a triple zero at $(0:1:0)$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn thank you and good point.